# Asset bundle is not loaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have created asset bundle with this script

```
using UnityEditor;

public class CreateAssetBundles
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
    static void BuildAllAssetBundles()
    {
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles/Images", BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64);
    }
}
```

But when I try to open my exe it says

> The file can not be loaded because it was created for another build target that is not compatible with this platform.
>   Please make sure to build AssetBundles using the build target platform that it is used by.
>   File's Build target is: 9

I also tried

```
BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows
```

And it does not work too.

So why it could happen and how to fix it?

Comment: **File** -> **Build Settings** select **PC,Mac & Linux Standalone** then click **Switch Platform**. Rebuild AssetBundle again.

Comment: platform has switched after first build and after this I made the asset bundle again, and this did not help

Comment: yeah, the same error

Comment: i dropped my answer. Hopefully that should solve your problem. If not save and restart Unity.

Answer (score 0):

> Please make sure to build AssetBundles using the build target platform
>   that it is used by. File's Build target is: 9.

According to Unity's documentation, Build target 9 is for `iOS`. You are either in `iOS` mode or `BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64` is not actually building the AssetBundle for `WinStandalone`. Unfortunately, you mentioned that you switched Platform and the problem but that didn't solve the problem.

Make sure that your Platform is set to `Windows Standalone Build`.

Go to `File` -> `Build Settings` -> select `PC,Mac & Linux Standalone` then click `Switch Platform`. Rebuild it again.

Now, replace:

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles/Images", BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64);
```

with

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles/Images", BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget);
```

Build the AssetBundle again.

Using `EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget` will force Unity to build the AssetBundle with the current active platform.

Comment: Note that you must do this for all other AssetBundles too. So make use to rebuild all of them with the new Script.

Comment: I did all you said but the error is still there. File's build target is still 9

Comment: This is wired. What Unity version are you running?

Comment: the last one, 5.3.5 i guess

Comment: I don't know what's going on with your version. This should solve your problem. Try UNITY 5.4.0F1. That's the version I am using. It will be released this month but is available for download right now. http://unity3d.com/unity/beta

Comment: ok, i have installed beta version of Unity and made asset bundle with it, the size of this asset bundle is different from the old one, so i thought that it's a solution, but! it still says that File's Build Target is 9

Comment: You mean even after updating, it's still saying **The file can not be loaded because it was created for another build target that is not compatible with this platform** ? It's not working?

Comment: I am not having that problem. What build is selected in your build settings?

Comment: windows ofc, I have built exe

Comment: That's no such thing as windows in the Build settings. What's the full name of the platform you chose?

Comment: here is a screenshot, Target platform: Windows http://puu.sh/q6WUY/ea1274452e.png

Comment: Actauuly, I was talking about the **PC,Mac & Linux Standalone** option which is under what you posted. My last suggestion to you is to create a simple new Project and try it again. See if that simple new project works with your newly  built asset bundle. If that did not work then file a bug by going to **Help** -> **Report a Bug**

Comment: i found the answer

Answer (score 0):

I download the bundle with

```
WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(path, 1);
```

So, as you already understand, it uses the same cache for different platforms, that's why I get iOS bundle for Windows build (because before this I tested it with iOS platform, ahahahah)